# asp.net mvc c# - property EntryList of ViewData class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I dont know where is my problem to access *EntryList* in ViewData.

```
  <%= Html.RenderPartial("LogOnControl", new NISE.Web.TestForum.Views.Shared.PaginationViewData()
  {
      PageIndex = ViewData.*EntryList*.PageIndex,
      TotalPages = ViewData.*EntryList*.TotalPages,
      PageActionLink = Url.Action("List","Entry", new { category = ViewData.Category, page = "{page}"}),
      TotalCount = ViewData.*EntryList*.TotalCount,
      PageSize = ViewData.*EntryList*.PageSize
  }, null)%>
```

I did everything like [here](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/04/08/aspnet-mvc-pagination-view-user-control/)

but it doesnt works... :(

Comment: “It doesn’t work” doesn’t say much. Provide more information about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the comments posted on the blog entry you linked to says:

> I’m trying with MVC Preview 3 but at the view form the system do not find ViewData.EntryList. Where is it?

The answer was:

> You need a strongly typed ViewData class – EntryList is just a sample property in this ViewDataClass. Here is a nice blogpost about strongly typed ViewData classes:
>   http://blog.codeville.net/2008/02/21/aspnet-mvc-making-strongly-typed-viewpages-more-easily/